# Is there a way to use multiple key selector to sort with UILocalizedIndexedCollation?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to sort CNContacts to create section indexes for TableView using UILocalizedIndexedCollation.  I can't find a way to sort using multiple keys like familyName and givenName.  I have tried using arrays and tuples, but no mater what I try it seems that the Selector can only accept a single character string.  Is there anyway to pass the selector multiple keys?

```
class SectionIndexesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current()
    var sections: [[CNContact]] = []
    var sectionTitles: [String] = []
    var contacts: [CNContact] = [] {
        didSet {
            sectionTitles.removeAll()
            sections.removeAll()
            let selector: Selector = #selector(getter: CNContact.familyName)
//            let selector: Selector = #selector(getter: (CNContact.familyName, CNContact.givenName))  // Error: Instance member 'familyName' cannot be used on type 'CNContact'
            var sectionsAll = Array(repeating: [], count: collation.sectionTitles.count)
            let sortedContacts = collation.sortedArray(from: contacts, collationStringSelector: selector)
            for contact in sortedContacts {
                let sectionNumber = collation.section(for: contact, collationStringSelector: selector)
                sectionsAll[sectionNumber].append(contact as! CNContact)
            }
            for index in 0 ..< sectionsAll.count {
                if sectionsAll[index].count > 0 {
                    sectionTitles.append(collation.sectionTitles[index])
                    sections.append(sectionsAll[index] as! [CNContact])
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch:
            [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)])
        fetchRequest.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.userDefault
        let store = CNContactStore()
        do {
            try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (contact, stop) -> Void in
                self.contacts.append(contact)
            })
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to create an extension to CNContact that has a read-only property that returns a single string built by concatenating the family and given names in the order you want the sort to happen.

Once that extension is setup, pass that property as the selector to UILocalizedIndexedCollation.

Comment: Wow! this was a good and easy solution to implement.  Thanks for the tip.  This is an example of where I've been struggling, moving from following tutorials to designing my own code.  I don't know when and where to use what.

Answer (score 0):

This is how easy the solution was:

```
extension CNContact {

    @objc var sortKey: String {
        get {
            return familyName + givenName
        }
    }
}
```

And change the select statement as follows:

```
let selector: Selector = #selector(getter: CNContact.sortKey)
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to put a comma or other punctuation between the family and given name to avoid some possible edge cases.